# Tensorflow Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [20] rhs shape= [48]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am a TensorFlow noob. I have trained a TensorFlow model from the open source implementation of deeppose and have to now run the model against a new set of images.

The model was trained on images of size `100 * 100` so I have resized the new set of images to the same size. I have `149` new images to run the model against. When I run the model, I get the following error.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes
of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [20] rhs shape= [48]
```

At the line

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
```

I suspect the trained model size and the test image sizes are not matching. I am not clear how to fix this issue. I printed out the list of variables from the `tf.all_variables()` call. Here it is

```
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(128, 100, 100, 3), dtype=float32)
(11, 11, 3, 20)
conv1/weights:0
(20,)
conv1/biases:0
(5, 5, 20, 35)
conv2/weights:0
(35,)
conv2/biases:0
(3, 3, 35, 50)
conv4/weights:0
(50,)
conv4/biases:0
(3, 3, 50, 75)
conv5/weights:0
(75,)
conv5/biases:0
(300, 1024)
local1/weights:0
(1024,)
local1/biases:0
(1024, 1024)
local2/weights:0
(1024,)
local2/biases:0
(1024, 0)
softmax_linear/weights:0
(0,)
softmax_linear/biases:0
```

I am not sure where the RHS parameter is coming from. I've looked at all config files and there doesn't seem to be any parameter specifying this config.

Any help in resolving this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), reshape=True)`

Comment: Can you show bigger stacktrace?

Comment: @Fake - The reshape didn't work, but I have solved the issue. Thanks mate

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try deleting any checkpoints that were saved from previous runs. Sometimes when changing the architecture and running again, TF will pick up from the old checkpoint (but with new definition), and you get this error.

Comment: Fantastic hint!

Comment: That was it. Thanks

Comment: Agree. I have just got this mistake today.

I re-train a model with a new configuration without changing its logdir, then TF picked up the old checkpoint and raised an error of mismatch.

Changing to another logdir fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem, the problem was that the labels and class numbers didn't matched so I changed and fix the class number cound and labels everywhere.

In my case it was to change the "num_classes" parameter in the faster_rcnn.config
and the "label_map.pbtxt" file to match with the real values.

Comment: Adding relevant code snippet along with an explanation really helps the future readers. It would be great if you can add those.

Comment: I added the changes I need to fix, but it could be different in each case, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If deleting checkpoints didn't work, this error is due to dimensions, so chek if the number of classes correspond to the same, as well as the dimensions of the image

Answer (score 1):

So as it happens, I had updated the TensorFlow code but had failed to train it. So I rolled back to the previous version, made the appropriate new changes to the run script and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens that the input image shape doesn't match with the input image tensor. Meaning, you may experience this problem when the model is expecting to have an input image as RGB but you are sending it Gray scale image. So, make sure to have the right input data. Check it by using the image.shape function of opencv.

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
h, w, c = im.shape
print(h,w,c)
```

where;
h is height
w is width
c is channel

Answer (score -2):

In my case the num_classes in training/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco.config file was not correct. Hence got this error.